# Validating if a string is a valid ARGB

Tags: c#, typescript

I want to validate if a string is valid ARGB.

E.g. #ffffffff is ARGB 255,255,255,255

How can I validate this using TypeScript and C#?

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For either language, you can use regular expressions to ensure a string matches your expectations. Here are some examples in Typescript and C#.

Typescript

```
const argbRegex = /^#[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$/;
argbRegex.test("#ffffffff"); // true
argbRegex.test("#gggggggg"); // false
```

C#

```
Regex argbRegex = new Regex("^#[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$");
argbRegex.IsMatch("#ffffffff"); // True
argbRegex.IsMatch("#gggggggg"); // False
```

Since you didn't mention it in your question, there are some things that you might want to consider that I did not cover:

- Should a 3 character RGB string be a valid ARGB string?
- Should a 6 character RGB string be a valid ARGB string?
- Do you strictly require the # symbol?
- Do you need to extract the decimal values for each ARGB component?

However, if all you need to do is validate the string is strictly in the 8 characters ARGB format, the above examples will work ok.